# Remote control software with disabled monitors

Tags: windows-10, display, remote-access

I have a set up of a group of computers running Windows 10. I am physically located with the computers, and want to switch between them using a KVM.

So I have a pair of monitors connected via KVM to four computers. I want to be able to work on computer 1 but also have someone else remote in and use TeamViewer (or similar) to control computer 2. However, when I switch away computer 2 now detects that its monitors are disconnected and consequently can't be used.

I don't want to use remote desktop because I want to be able to see what the remote workers are doing. Is there a way to tell Windows "Use these monitor settings, and keep using them even if you detect a monitor disconnect?"

Answer (score 2):

You didnt mention the make and model of your KVM switch, which might help in determining your issue.  It sounds like you have a passive KVM switch.

KVM switches are either active or passive. Passive switches are typically hardwired internally between their input and output ports. Computers connected to a passive switch are typically selected manually on the switch itself. Active switches maintain the connections to keyboards, mice, and monitors connected to them.

Since an active KVM switch fools the computer into thinking the devices are still connected to the computer, the computer does not disconnect the devices via plug & play, which I believe is causing your issue.

Replacing your passive KVM switch with an active one, should solve the problem.  There may by software solutions, but I am not aware of any.